# Reality check: Could a diamagnetic gold shell around a planet exist?

Tags: internal-consistency, electromagnetism, dyson-spheres

Could a gold shell around a planet exist, suspended by a magnetic field (gold is diamagnetic), given the following constraints?

- A gold layer enveloping a planet, **arbitrarily thin**.
- **Unspecified height**, likely to be where atmosphere is less dense with fewer jumps of pressure.
- a strong magnetic field that repels the gold and keeps it suspended **thanks to gold's diamagnetic properties** exists or was created.
- **No specific function has to be performed by the sphere, just aesthetics**. Make the planet shiny as a gold ball.
- An alien race has sufficient energy reserves (e.g. huge uranium deposits) to avoid relying on solar panels. They prefer being shiny instead of using solar power.
- The sphere should not be built, it just needs to be kept suspended ( so I do not need to know how it was built, that's another problem, just need to know if it can be maintained)

Comment: Dyson spheres aren't planets, so this question is very confusing.

Comment: If the residents of the planet were very, very shy, or excessively paranoid about privacy, they might want to cover their entire planet with a thin opaque film that not even radar could penetrate.

Comment: Plus one for making me look up diamagnetic properties, something I did not know about.

Comment: dyson spheres cover suns

Comment: Dyson spheres cover whatever star system body you want them to cover. I mean, what else would you call a sphere that envelopes a planet?

Comment: Wouldn't a dyson sphere around a planet with an atmosphere be held up simply by air pressure, like a huge balloon around the planet? I could see using the diamagnetic property to BUILD the sphere, using it to hold the sections in place until they formed the continuous skin of the balloon. I can, however, see a complication with particles, solar wind, solar flares, ionization, magnetic fields, conductive gold foil, induction, eddy currents, chaotic fields, and diamagnetic properties. A huge Van de Graaf generator sphere around the planet? Better than solar energy, a continuous lightning storm.

Comment: I think a better term to use here than dyson sphere may be firmament.

Comment: *Make the planet shiny as a gold ball.*  Your sole objective seems to be making the planet shiny.  But planets stick out like a sore thumb already apart from the night side (and your thin shell won't change that).  When you think "planet" think "moon" or "venus" or "jupiter" - all very visible even on Earth's surface.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond: Atmospheric pressure won't keep the sphere up. Think about it. Imagine the sphere with the planet at the center, and then imagine it with the planet touching the interiour surface. What is the force which favors the first situation over the second?

Comment: @AlexP Boyle's law.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond: Hoe does Boyle's law distinguish between the sphere being equidistant from the Earth inside and the sphere touching the surface of the Earth? The volume between the sphere and the Earth is the same in both situations (obviously).

Comment: @AlexP ????? Because atmospheric pressure is fairly consistent all around the planet, and the pressure on the balloon would be equal at all points around its surface, because the volume of air between the earth and the balloon surface would be equal all around the sphere. The catch is that the atmospheric pressure gradient is due to the gravitational effects of the earth on the atmosphere, and not on the concept of 'blowing up a balloon' producing the pressure. Works as long as the pressure in the contained area is due primarily to this gravity-induced pressure, and not due to being enclosed,

Comment: That is, the foil lies on top of the pressure, it does not create it.

Comment: @AlexP But alas I now see your point. An interesting plot twist. If the atmosphere heats up sufficiently inside the air-tight sphere (global warming, anyone?) then the pressure would become much greater than normal atmospheric pressure due to gravity, and all hell would break lose.  The sphere would be able to wobble around the earth willy-nilly. But also the people in the sphere would be crushed by the pressure like a ,,, well.... bug under a boot. Or more accurately a submarine at the bottom of the ocean.

Comment: A plot twist - the pressure builds up, the balloon free-wheels around the earth, is punctured by Mount Everest, the air whooshes out of the hole, taking atmosphere with it, and the earth is set off course by Newton's Law. OOOOhh, interesting disaster scenario.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond: That is a *great* idea!

Comment: @ CoffeDeveloper  Why would the natives use uranium fission for power if their advanced technology probably has fusion power generation?  They will probably produce their gold by fusion of lighter elements, and fusion of gold would take a lot of energy, presumably produced by thermonuclear fusion.

Answer (score 4):

Not likely, but maybe you could use dust?

First, as mentioned by @JustinThymetheSecond, the magnetic field around a planet is not static.  Earth's magnetic field is pushed around constantly by the Sun, meaning anything that tries to be kept suspended by this field would quickly be pushed apart.  A related issue is that as this foil is pushed around, large eddy currents will form - likely melting the foil.

Second, anything that reflects light will also be pushed by the "light pressure" - the same concept that is used for solar sails will ram any gold foil into your planet.

Third, unless you have openings in this gold foil, it will slowly inflate due to the planet off-gassing.  Normally, a planet's atmosphere slowly boils away into space, being replenished by gases released from natural or other processes on the planet.  This inflation will eventually rip the foil apart.

Cool idea, and you could maybe use gold dust, or some other "shiny" **particle** to get a similar effect - just note that it will need to be continually replenished.  Particles would avoid most of these issues, but there will be a "trail" of particles both into the planet's atmosphere and streaming outward from the planet away from its sun.  They will still block a lot of the incoming light, as well - depending on the concentration.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking gold foil shreds, like chaff is used to mask radar signals.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond - chaff could work too, but if it’s a massive connected sheet, it’ll have problems.

Comment: And loosely overlapped sheets without connections?

Comment: It.s the fact that gold is extremely electrically conductive that is the problem - more conductive than copper, by far. The sheets would have to be electrically insulated from each other, so that an electric current could not flow throughout the entire surface.

Answer (score 1):

Freeman Dyson's theory was never talking about an actual sphere built around a star, but a swarm. encasing a star around a sphere is impossible with existing materials, so the best you can get is building a dyson swarm. I.E. a cloud of stations or panels enveloping the star.

the same can actually be done with planets, Albeit never as powerful as an actual dyson swarm given you can only harvest a billionth of the energy from the star.

we see such things in the Mobile-suit Gundam anime, albeit not what you are directly asking.

but as for making the swarm of panels look like a sphere, you can simply use orbital mechanics to orbit the plates. and enough of them would make the planet from a distance look like a gold sphere.